# How to convert Float(Wrapper class) to Integer wrapper class?

Tags: java

how to convert Float to Integer in java?

```
Float value = 30.0F
```

how to convert above value to Integer?

Please help me?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `Float.intValue()`:

```
Integer i = value.intValue();
```

Note that this causes autoboxing, but since you're planning to create an `Integer` anyway, this won't have any performance impact.

Note also that you should pay attention to rounding: `intValue()` and an `int` cast round toward zero. For rounding to the nearest integer, use `Math.round()`, for rounding down use `Math.floor()`, for rounding up use `Math.ceil()`. If you need some other kind of rounding, you need to implement it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Float f = new Float(10.5);
Integer i = new Integer((int)Math.ceil(f));
```

f.intValue() is the way to go..

Comment: +1 because this makes the necessary rounding explicit (although you might want elaborate on this a little)

Answer (score 0):

Use `value.intValue()` method.

```
Float value = 30.0F;
Integer intValue=Integer.valueOf(value.intValue());
```

Answer (score 0):

`new Float(value).intValue()` or simly cast it to int `int v = (int) value`

Comment: He want's an `Integer`, not an `int`.

Comment: Your second example won't work (compile time error). You would need to do `(int) (float) value`.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do this:

```
Float value = 30.0f;
Integer intVal = value.intValue(); // auto-boxing happens here
```